# Command Line output still remains as null using WMIC, but displays in taskmgr gui (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

the below shows display in the GUI of `frmweb.exe` process ( attached `image/png` )
where command line arguments are visible.

when the same is tried to be captured via command line it throws null.
steps below is pasted as text. Need help with this, thanks

```
wmic path win32_process get name, commandline /format:"%WINDI%\System32\wbem\csv" | find "frmweb.exe" >  commandline.txt

notepad commandline.txt

vbox_host,,frmweb.exe
vbox_host
vbox_host,,frmweb.exe
vbox_host
vbox_host,,frmweb.exe
vbox_host
vbox_host,,frmweb.exe
vbox_host
vbox_host,,frmweb.exe
vbox_host
vbox_host,,frmweb.exe
vbox_host
vbox_host,,frmweb.exe
vbox_host
vbox_host,,frmweb.exe
vbox_host
vbox_host,,frmweb.exe
vbox_host
vbox_host,find  "frmweb.exe" ,find.exe
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: you're sure, that format works? I guess, it should just be `/format:csv`

Comment: yes, an error popped out saying .xsl file was not in path, hence had to give complete path, after copying from en-us folder....i think this might be a windows bug

Comment: Did you specifically set a variable named `%WINDI%`? and why didn't you just leave the xsl file in the en-US directory and include that in the full path instead? In order to test whether or not it's an issue with the xsl or with WMIC, have you tried different formats? And have you tried other WMI or CIM scripting languages?

Comment: without even adding the /format: its not working as exepected.

Comment: lets leave the formatting aside.,
c:\> wmic path win32_process get name, commandline | clip
even this above is not working as expected.

Comment: @NizamudeenA What did you get when you try like this in the cmd : `wmic path win32_process get name, commandline /Value | find /I "frmweb.exe"` ?

Comment: i get this

Node,CommandLine,Name
vbox_host,,"frmweb.exe"

on doing below

c:\>wmic path win32_process get name,commandline /format:"c:\test\
csv" | clip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to ensure that you have actually tried to use a correct command, this is how I would probably perform the task using `WMIC`:

```dos
WMIC Process Where "Name='frmweb.exe'" Get CommandLine,Name /Format:"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\en-US\csv.xsl">"CommandLines.csv"
```

Because you've copied your `csv.xsl` file to `C:\Windows\System32\wbem`:

```dos
WMIC Process Where "Name='frmweb.exe'" Get CommandLine,Name /Format:csv >commandline.txt
```

If you're specifically wishing to exclude the header then:

```dos
WMIC Process Where "Name='frmweb.exe'" Get CommandLine,Name /Format:csv|Find ".">commandline.txt
```

---

I have a feeling that the comma in your CommandLine is causing the issue.

It may help if you change the way the results are transformed into output, so here's a suggestion.

Open the `csv.xsl` you've copied to `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem` in a text editor and change the line:

```xml
<xsl:template match="VALUE" xml:space="preserve"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>
```

To:

```xml
<xsl:template match="VALUE" xml:space="preserve">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:template>
```

The idea being that you're asking it to doublequote each value field of the csv output.

---

To ensure that the output is not actually null, you could test the command from `PowerShell` instead:

```ps1
GWMI Win32_Process -F "Name='frmweb.exe'"|Select Name,CommandLine|Export-CSV -U -NoT .\commandline.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.,

--using poweshell admin
GWMI Win32_Process -F "Name='frmweb.exe'"|Select Name,CommandLine,processid >  "c:\test\CommandLinePS.csv" 
 
--using commandwindow admin
WMIC Process Where "Name='frmweb.exe'" Get CommandLine,Name,Processid /Format:"C:\test\csv.xsl" > "c:\test\CommandLineBAT.csv"

Comment: and that c:\test\csv.xsl had your changes #compo.
much thanks; comma is all that hindered the expectations. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To catch the commandline of your process `frmweb.exe` with a batch file :

```dos
@echo off
Set "Process=frmweb.exe"
wmic path win32_process Get Name,Commandline /format:csv | find /I "%Process%" | findstr /i /v "find" >CommandLine.txt
Start "" CommandLine.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by running the command prompt as Administrator. Then WMIC was able to show the CommandLine successfully just like the Task Manager GUI.